# Conversion of Sirgas2000 projection system to wgs84

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I am having a bunch of .csv files containing "x" and "y" of some locations (to be specific, Brazil and the coordinate system is SIRGAS 2000). I want to convert them into wgs84 i.e, lat/long using arcpy and rewrite the .csv files having lat/longs to corresponding "x" and"y" using python. Can anyone please help me doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option to create the arcpy code:

1. Create a ModelBuilder model
2. Add/connect [Make XY Event Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00170000006z000000) -> [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) -> [Project](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) -> [Add XY Coordinates](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) -> [Copy Rows](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-rows.htm) tools, and define all parameters and run model.  This will convert your .csv table to a layer that you can re-project and add new x/y field with the 4326 coord values
3. Finally, in the model export out python script, Model (menu) -> Export -> To Python Script...

This will produce the related arcpy/python script which you may use and tweek as needed.

Comment: I have a doubt...does this Project take .csv files directly??

Comment: @Nil, updated my answers to handle initial .csv data.